# Long vs long as param type in the Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I always have this dilemma coming up when deciding to use Long or long as type for Controller/Service method parameters.

Should I use a Long because Hibernate suggests to use reference types which means I have to add a null check in the Service or should I just use long and have an exception thrown?

```
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteById(@PathVariable Long id) throws LookServiceException {
lookService.deleteById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the method you are calling shouldn't dictate the parameter.

You should use `Long` for the parameter if it is optional (`required = false`) and `long` if it isn't.

Then, you can just use autoboxing for `deleteById` and it will automatically convert the `Long` to a `long`:

```java
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteById(@PathVariable long id) throws LookServiceException {
    lookService.deleteById(id);
}
```

You might also want to change the `deleteById` in your `lookService` to use `long` instead of `Long` if `null` elements don't make sense for it (deleting a nonexisting element doesn't seem to make sense). If you are  just using a `Long` parameter due to `CrudRepository`'s `deleteById` method, I would make the `lookService.deleteById` accept a `long` parameter as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would it be more appropriate to use long in the Service method as a null value (with Long) is not acceptable?

Comment: If you don't want `null` somewhere, use `long` unless you have a good reason not to. If it might be optional in some way, you might still want to think about using a special value like `-1` instead of `null` though (but if you prefer `null`, you'd use `Long`).

Comment: I really want to follow Hibernate's approach of Long (reference-type) but isn't it a bit too much to have such a null check for every request in both Controller/Service?

I'll leave aside my personal opinions. How would you do in professionally sir?

Comment: Nothing stops you from using the wrapper fof JPA/Hibernate related code. But that doesn't mean you should makd everything `Long`. If you don't need nullness in some method, use the primitive `long`. Hibernate preferring the wrapper type in some part of your code shouldn't force you into using it somewhere else. You might even want to have your controller be independent of the DB logic.

Answer (score 3):

The decision between using Long (reference type) or long (primitive type) for method parameters **often depends on your specific use case** and requirements, i.e. whether it can be `null` or not and so on.

In the case of a `@PathVariable`, it doesn't really make sense for them to be `Long` and be null, because it is not optional, so you can not pass anything in your URL, otherwise you'll get 404.

In the case of Hibernate-entity, Hibernate often prefers using `Long` because it allows distinguishing between a newly created entity (with a null id) and a persistent entity with a non-null id.

Here are main differences to make decision between primitive or wrapper:

**Nullability**:

Primitives cannot be null, while wrapper classes can. If you need to represent the absence of a value or an uninitialized state, you may opt for a wrapper class.

**Default Values**:

Primitives have default values (e.g., 0 for int, 0.0 for double), while wrapper classes default to null. This can affect the behavior of your code, especially if you want to distinguish between an explicitly set 0 and an uninitialized state.

**Memory Overhead**:

Primitives generally have lower memory overhead compared to their wrapper classes. If memory efficiency is crucial, especially in large-scale applications or tight memory environments, using primitives can be beneficial.

**Performance**:

Operations on primitives are often faster than on their corresponding wrapper classes. Autoboxing (converting a primitive to its wrapper) and unboxing (converting a wrapper to its primitive) operations can introduce overhead, especially in tight loops or performance-critical sections.

**Collections and Generics**:

Collections in Java (e.g., List, Set, Map) can only store objects, not primitives. If you need to use primitives in collections, you might have to use wrapper classes or use specialized collections from libraries like Trove or Eclipse Collections.
Generics do not support primitive types directly; you have to use wrapper classes when generics are involved.

Comment: I want to note that the parameter of `deleteById` must be `Long` because it's a generic, not because of the `@Id` being `Long`. If the primary key attribute was a `long`, `deleteById` would still accept a `Long` parameter.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying, which `deleteById` method do you mean?

Comment: The one provided by Spring's `CrudRepository` since that's what I think the OP is using internally (they mentioned using Spring and hibernate).

Comment: @dan1stiscrying, and what do you mean by your comment then? I didn't write that the parameter in `deleteById` in `CrudRepository` Id must be Long because @Id in entity is Long.  I wrote that in ENTITY it must be `Long`, pls read my answer carefully

Comment: Yes I did read that. I didn't write my comment as a correction (your answer is perfectly fine) but rather as a side note.